# I want to show upcoming gigs announcements in my home page

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oRlh.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Obeqk.png)This is my Homecontroller:

```js
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public HomeController()
        {
            _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
        
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var upcomingGigs = _context.Gigs
                .Include(g => g.Artist)
                .Include(g => g.Genre)
                .Where(g => g.DateTime > DateTime.Now);

            return View(upcomingGigs);
        }
```

  @foreach (var gig in Model)
       {
- @gig.DateTime.ToString("MMM")
                  
                  
                      @gig.DateTime.ToString("d ")
                  

              

              
                  
                      @gig.Artist.Name

  ```html
  @model IEnumerable<BigHub.Models.Gig>
  @{
      ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

  }



  <ul>


      @foreach (var gig in Model)
       {
          <li>
              <div class="date">
                  <div class="month">
                      @gig.DateTime.ToString("MMM")
                  </div>
                  <div class="day">
                      @gig.DateTime.ToString("d ")
                  </div>

              </div>

              <div class="details">
                  <span class="artist">
                      @gig.Artist.Name
                  </span>
                  <span class="genre">
                      @gig.Genre.Name
                  </span>

              </div>
          </li>
       }


  </ul>
  ```
  }

This code is working but I'm getting
output empty.I hope some one can help.

This is my expected output

This is my output

Comment: Can you go into more detail as to what exactly you want to accomplish, like illustrations or live site examples?

Comment: And show what you've tried so far, please.

Comment: I'm debugging but getting empty <ul></ul> list.

Answer (score 1):

In the first place, you need to add **`ToList()`** at the end. Try this exactly:

```
var upcomingGigs = _context.Gigs
                .Include("Artist")
                .Include("Genre").ToList();
```

Secondly, your where clause is not correct if it tries to perform filtering on a column belonging to tables inside **Include()**.

I recommend creating a ViewModel like this:

```
public class Movie_ViewModel
{
    public string genreName { get; set; }
    public string artistName { get; set; }
    public string movieDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Now, in the Controller, assuming the `DateTime column` belongs to the `Gigs table`:

```
List<Movie_ViewModel> upcomingGigs = _context.Gigs.Where(g => g.DateTime > DateTime.Now)
                .Include("Artist")
                .Include("Genre")
                .Select( m => new Movie_ViewModel{
                                          genreName = m.Genre.Name,
                                          artistName = m.Artist.Name,
                                          movieDateTime = m.DateTime
                      })
                .ToList();

return View(upcomingGigs);
```

And finally, in your View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Path.To.Movie_ViewModel>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    item.genreName  . . . 
}
```

Hope this helped :)